# Regex to extract specific number from the URL based on the URL pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract the number from the URL. Here is the code I tried:

```
urlss = 'http://www.deyi.com/thread-24488-1-1.html'
urlss = re.sub('http://www.deyi.com/thread-(.*?)-1-1.html', '', urlss)
print(urlss)
```

My expected result is the below number:

```
24488
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`re.sub`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) replaces the content in the string. You need to use [**`re.search`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) to extract the substring. You can use below regex to extract your desired number from url:

```
'(?<=thread-)\d+'
```

This regex will return the string of first continuous series of number just after the "thread-".

For example:

```
>>> urlss = 'http://www.deyi.com/thread-24488-1-1.html'
>>> import re

>>> re.search('(?<=thread-)\d+', urlss).group()
'24488'
```

Comment: Ok,Thank you for your answer！

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Positive Lookahead (?=(\d+))`

```
import re
urlss = 'http://www.deyi.com/thread-24488-1-1.html'

pattern='thread-(?=(\d+))'

match=re.search(pattern,urlss)
print(match.group(1))
```

output:

```
24488
```

If every time url pattern is same only some variable or pages chainging then you can use simple pattern like this:

```
import re
urlss = 'http://www.deyi.com/thread-24488-1-1.html'

pattern='(\d+){2}'

match=re.search(pattern,urlss)
print(match.group())
```

output:

```
24488
```